# Как проверить существование записи в INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql

Есть несколько таблиц из которых происходит выборка

```
SELECT studentapplication.id, 
       studentapplication.studentid, 
       category, 
       subcategory, 
       langcategory, 
       comment, 
       time, 
       currenttime, 
       status, 
       avatar, 
       auth.name, 
       auth.surname, 
       auth.patronymic 
FROM   `studentapplication` 
       INNER JOIN auth 
               ON studentapplication.studentid = auth.id 
       INNER JOIN studentapplicationconfirmedby 
               ON studentapplicationconfirmedby.teacherid <> :user_id 
                  AND studentapplicationconfirmedby.idapply = 
                      studentapplication.id 
                  AND (SELECT* 
                       FROM   `studentapplicationconfirmedby` 
                       WHERE  studentapplicationconfirmedby.idapply = 
                              studentapplication.id) 
WHERE  `status` = :satusApp_id;
```

Теперь цель. В таблице `studentApplicationConfirmedBy` может присутствовать и не присутствовать запись для операции `ON`, мне же нужно добавлять данный `INNER JOIN` только в случае существования записи по `` (SELECT*FROM `studentApplicationConfirmedBy` WHERE studentApplicationConfirmedBy.idApply = studentApplication.id) ``. В противном случае или не ставить `INNER JOIN` на эту таблицу или же убирать условие `studentApplicationConfirmedBy.idApply = studentApplication.id`.
Моя логика была следующей: так как мы добавили `` (SELECT*FROM `studentApplicationConfirmedBy` WHERE studentApplicationConfirmedBy.idApply = studentApplication.id) ``, то в случае пустого ответа от запроса, будет false и объединения по другим полям не будет, но это не сработало (ошибка: [21000][1241] Operand should contain 1 column(s)).
Как это реализовать?
(p.s извините за отсутствие переноса строк)

Comment: В следующий раз что бы не получать минусы за вопросы, форматируйте так что бы было удобно ленивому человеку поделиться с вами своими знаниями и вникнуть в вашу проблему, ваши извинения тут не прокатят. Есть полно онлайн сервисов форматирования кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT studentapplication.id, 
       studentapplication.studentid, 
       category, 
       subcategory, 
       langcategory, 
       comment, 
       time, 
       currenttime, 
       status, 
       avatar, 
       auth.name, 
       auth.surname, 
       auth.patronymic 
FROM   `studentapplication` 
       INNER JOIN auth 
               ON studentapplication.studentid = auth.id 
       LEFT JOIN studentapplicationconfirmedby 
               ON studentapplicationconfirmedby.teacherid <> :user_id 
                  AND studentapplicationconfirmedby.idapply = 
                      studentapplication.id 
WHERE  `status` = :satusApp_id;
```

Если я все правильно понял

Comment: Вы все правильно поняли) Глупый вопрос вышел, забыл про LEFT JOIN совершенно